# How to get a every `split()` function output to a variable if you don't know how much is it?

Tags: java, hash, split

I have a problem with my code and I don't know what to do to get this to work:
I have a `Redis` cache system that gets the information of a user from a String value and the value of that key is something like this in the user profile in `Redis` cache: `someinfo: "a:b:c/a:b:c/c:b:a/b:a:c"` and I need to get the information of each of the information's given inside the bar but to do that properly with the `split()` function I would need to know exactly how much bar's are in the value, I would like to get every information inside the bar in as a variable, but the amount of bar's could be 2, 3, 4 or even 50, I don't have that information, is it even possible to do what I want? Maybe using loops? Please help me, thanks in advance.

I want to get every information of a the split from '/' and then use split again to get the other information's by splitting ':' but in order to do that I would need to know exactly how much '/' are in the String in order to use split again but I don't have that information.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Are you trying to split the String by '/'? `split` dynamically creates the result array so you don't need to know how many values are the result of a split command.

Comment: @Timo Because I want to get every information of a the split from '/' and then use split again to get the other information's by splitting ':' but in order to do that I would need to know exactly how much '/' are in the String in order to use split again but I don't have that information.

Comment: "_is it even possible to do what I want?_" - Probably, yes - but you would have to _show_ us what you want using data and code, instead of only describing it (I do not understand the problem description in the question). So, you can [edit] the question to show some example inputs - and for each one, show the expected outcome. Also show us what you have tried and what happened when you tried it: show us the **relevant, minimal code** so we know what you are already able to do, even if it is not the solution you need.

Comment: @andrewJames How am I going to send a code that I don't even know how to do? That's why I'm asking the question, I still don't have the code done, the only thing I have is a String[] parts = value.split("/"); does that helps?

Comment: When you do the `String[] parts = value.split("/");` you can get the elements easily by `parts.length`. If you need the count. Otherwise simply iterator over the parts:
`for (String part : parts) { String[] elements = part.split(":"); }`

Comment: Yes, it absolutely helps us for you to show us `String[] parts = value.split("/");` in your question. That tells us a lot - and is much clearer than anything else in your question. For example, now I can assume that when you write "inside the bar", you actually mean "delimited by the forward slash". The code is clear. Like I said, it's perfectly OK to show us your code, even if it is wrong, or incomplete.